# Upgrading from 9 to 13, do I have to go through minor versions?

Tags: upgrade, versions

Can I go

```
9.04 -> 10.04 -> 11.04 -> 12.04 -> 13.04
```

Or do I need to go 'through' minor versions, i.e.

```
9.04 -> 9.10 -> 10.04 -> 10.10 -> 11.04 -> 11.10 -> 12.04 -> 12.10 -> 13.04
```

Comment: Possible answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: Besides it being a duplicate question ;) ... I would re-install. 1. Upgrading takes too long. 2. Upgrading will leave old, no longer used, files. 3. Upgrading a list like this has too many points of failure.

Comment: And 4) 9.04 has not been supported since October of 2010.  If you have really been running an unsupported, unpatched OS for 3 years, there is a very real chance your system has been hacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade from LTS to LTS so in theory you could do:

```
9.04 → 9.10 → 10.04 → 12.04 → 12.10 → 13.04
```

I'm not sure if the 9.10 repo still exists though as it's been decommissioned for a couple of years already so that may throw a massive spanner in the works.

But even if it did, that amount of bandwidth and the time spent unzipping all those updates... You'd be better off just with a clean install. It's faster and means there's much less chance of running into dodgy configuration issues (which *shouldn't* happen, but occasionally do).

Another idea is to get to 12.04 and use one of the HWE stacks to get a fresher kernel, driver and graphics stack. I'm not sure what you're after exactly but 12.04 is solid and it gives you a simple upgrade path to 14.04 in 7 months time.

Comment: 14.04? Are you from the future?

Comment: I am, but either way, I did say they could upgrade "in 7 months time" (when 14.04 is released).

Comment: Why wouldn't it be `9.04 -> 9.10 -> 10.04 -> 11.04 -> 12.04 -> 13.04` (why the `9.10`?).  Thanks.

Comment: No, LTS releases are two years apart.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry, still not seeing why the 9.10 version needs to be there but not 10.10, etc.  I must be missing something obvious perhaps?

Comment: 9.04, 9.10, 12.10 and 13.04 are all standard releases and their only upgrade path is the next release. 10.04 and 12.04 are LTS releases that can jump to the next LTS.